# In what conditions a quadratic function has an integer value of $f(x)$ where $x$ is also an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

**EDITED**

Sorry, the question was wrong. Please forgive me for this.

Suppose a quadratic function $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, what I want to know is if in an integer $x$, say $x=1, x=2, x=3, ...$, the function has also a corresponding integer value of $y$ or not ($y=1, y=2, y=5, ...$). Is there a way?

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ integers? Must both roots be integers?

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú - What if $f(x)=6(x-\frac{1}{2})(x-\frac{1}{3})$? Roots are rational but not integers.

Comment: $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ iff $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @RobArthan, I edited the question, please remove the "duplicated" tag as it is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @JavadKouhi: your edits completely changed the sense of your question.

Comment: @JavadKouhi: ... Please try to avoid irritating us all by being unapologetic about such messing around.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Set up
 $$ a(x- \alpha_1)(x - \alpha_2) = a x^2 + b x +c $$

where: $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ are the integer roots of the quadratic equation.

After that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = - \frac{b}{a} ;  \alpha_1 \alpha_2 = \frac{c}{a}$

I just realized that the above equations follow Vieta's formulas, then you can consider the cases to $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $a$ doesn't have to be 1, for the quadratic polynomial to have integer roots.

Comment: when finding the roots,  without lost of generality, we can assume $a =1$

Comment: Try $2x^2-8$ with $a=2$, and root $x=2$

Comment: @avid19 But all the coefficients in your case are multiples of the leading coefficient, hence the WLOG (I do agree that this should at least be *addressed* in the answer, though).

Comment: He should state that more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

For the revised question, you have $$f(0)=c$$So $c$ must be an integer, and $g(x)=f(x)-c=ax^2+bx$ will be an integer whenever $f(x)$ is an integer.

Now $g(1)=a+b$ and $g(-1)=a-b$ so we must have both $2a=g(1)+g(-1)$ and $2b=g(1)-g(-1)$ are integers. We also require $a\pm b$ are integers - so either $a,b$ are both integers or they are both half of odd integers. i.e. there are integers $c,d$ with $c=2a, d=2b$ and $2\mid c-d$

Note that $$g(x\pm1)=ax^2\pm 2ax+a+bx\pm b=g(x)\pm 2ax+(a\pm b)$$ and the conditions above are sufficient to ensure that this is an integer if $g(x)$ is. And of course $g(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A basis for the *integer-valued polynomials* (of whatever degree), as a $\mathbf Z$-module, is made up of the `binomial polynomials:
$$P_k(x)=\frac{x(x-1)\dotsm(x-k+1)}{k!}$$
Hence a quadratic integer-valued polynomial has the form:
$$f(x)=a\frac{x(x-1)}2+bx+c,\qquad(a,b,c\in\mathbf Z).$$